# Change Woocommerce order status programmatically

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to change order status by some conditionals by using woocommerce_thankyou action.

I created some custom order statuses with plugin:
[image]

By using this function - nothing happen, the status remain "in hold" and not changed as wishes:

```
/*after order done*/
function check_and_change_status($order_id){
    if ( is_checkout() && is_order_received_page() )  {
        
       $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
       $order_status = $order->get_status();
       $product_in_order = false;
       $items = $order->get_items(); 
       $count = 0;

       foreach ( $items as $item ) {      
           $product_id = $item->get_product_id();  
           $is_start_from_product = the_feild('get_an_offer',  $product_id);    
           $the_startFromPrice = the_feild('startFromPrice',  $product_id);
           $the_winningPrice = the_feild('winningPrice',  $product_id);

           if ($is_start_from_product && $count == 0) {
               $count++;

               $price_that_paid = $item->get_total();
               if($price_that_paid > $the_startFromPrice && $price_that_paid < $the_winningPrice){
                   $order->update_status('auctionpending');
               }elseif($price_that_paid > $the_winningPrice){
                    $order->update_status('auctionwon');
               }
           }elseif ($is_start_from_product && $count > 0) {
               /*Do it later*/
           }
       }
    }   
}
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou','check_and_change_status');
```

What i am missing?
The conditional are work well (I have been debugged that), but the order status not changed.

Answer (score 0):

You use **the_feild** in your foreach loop.
The wordpress function is **the_field.**

```
the_field($selector, [$post_id], [$format_value]);
```

Where **$selector** is your field name and **[$post_id]** is the place where your value is saved.

Edit that and try again

```
$is_start_from_product = the_field('get_an_offer',  $product_id);    
$the_startFromPrice = the_field('startFromPrice',  $product_id);
$the_winningPrice = the_field('winningPrice',  $product_id);
```